# How to select a position and add an item in a QGraphicsView by mouse click?

Tags: c++, qt, qgraphicsview

I would like to select positions and items in a `QGraphicsView` by mouse click and add items to the connected view at this position/item. Do I need to implement my own subclass of `QGraphicsView` or is there a shorter solution, e.g. with signal/slot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are few ways to do it:

- Reimplement `mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent*)` (so, you need to implement subclass of `QGraphicsView`),
- Call `installEventFilter(QObject *)` for `QGraphicsView` and implement `bool eventFilter(QObject *, QEvent *)` to catch all events (and process only `QEvent::MouseButtonPress` inside this function). In this case you do not need to implement subclass of `QGraphicsView`.

See also: [Click event for QGraphicsView Qt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16039020/click-event-for-qgraphicsview-qt) and [How to draw a point (on mouseclick) on a QGraphicsScene](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7830054/how-to-draw-a-point-on-mouseclick-on-a-qgraphicsscene)